# Elixir, Phoenix: inject parameters in action on routing step

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

Lets say we have some routes similar to these

```
get "/user-:user/", MyController, :same_action 
get "/user-:user/email-:email/", MyController, :same_action  
get "/user-:user/page-:page/", MyController, :same_action
```

First i thought it would be easy and all I need just add something in route string

```
get "/user-:user/page-:page/", MyController, :same_action, :some_custom_value
```

But now i`ve stuck
All i want is to handle them with one action, but in need to figure out somehow... (in controller maybe)... which route was matched and do something like:

```
def same_method(conn, params_parsed_from_url) do
  make_search_by(params_parsed_from_url, some_custom_value)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to do something different for each of them, wouldn't it be better to point them to different actions?

Comment: Actualy i want to do same but with one extra param.

Comment: You should be able to pattern match on the params, in case you need to handle it separately. Have you tried that?

Comment: sure, i have few solutions, including the one you mentioned, in case i won't succeed to find more elegant))